# X11 GUI performance

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I am working on a portable GUI toolkit for Linux and Windows and stuck on some performance problem. On several systems (as my netbook based on the infamous Intel GMA 3650) is very highly affected by the driver installed.

But what is the paradox, when the fallback VESA driver is installed, the performance of my code is **much higher** than with the dedicated proprietary driver.

On the other hand with the proprietary driver, **as expected** the performance of the computer is very good. Hardware acceleration works, high definition videos are played without problems and this way only **my code** is affected in this strange reverse manner.

My code uses common libraries like Xlib, Xft, pthreads, etc.

The Windows port (uses WinApi) runs in great speed without any problems. Even in Wine. As an another paradox, the same program, compiled for Windows and running in WINE draws much faster than the Linux compiled program.

What can be the reason for this effect and where to dig in order to fix it.

The source code repository is [managed by fossil scm](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/index)

One test example is in `trunk/freshlib/TestFreshLib.fpr` (for plain FASM compile `freshlib/test_code0/TestLib.asm`)

This is portable example and can be compiled for Windows and Linux as well.

**Update 1:** After some thought and code exploration, I have an hypothesis. I am using two different methods to draw the graphics on the windows:

1. Using XLib drawing functions for drawing lines and rectangles.
2. Using Xft library to draw the texts.

The controls I am testing use double buffering where the image buffer is a pixmap on the server side.

But IIRC, Xft draws on the client side and then sends the image as a bitmap image to the X server, while XLib draws directly on the server side.

Is it possible some conflict between these two methods (and somehow connection with the hardware acceleration) to cause this performance degradation?

Comment: This sounds most incredible. Can you isolate the problem into an SSCCE?

Comment: What is SSCCE? Note, I am not an expert in C/C++ or even Linux/X11 programming. :)

Comment: Ah, I got it "Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example". But unfortunately no. I can of course point you to the repository - it is an open source, but there is a pretty big bunch of files and I don't know where to search the problem. (and it is in assembly language :))

Comment: A repo link should be OK, I will try to test this.

Comment: @n.m. - I put a link to the repository at the question itself. If you have problems with the compilation - just ask.

Comment: Sorry I haven't got a chance to look at your code yet. Have you tried to profile it? When you rn it, does your ptocess or the X server process take a lot of the CPU percentage?

Comment: @n.m. - if the code was simply slow, I would probably fixed it by myself. But it is slow only on some circumstances, related to the hardware drivers and Linux system architecture - an area where I am absolute beginner. So, I even can't figure out where to start the search.

Comment: If you have a system where your program runs slow, run it, then run the `top` command in a separate terminal. Look at the output. It will show which process is the top CPU hog. If it's your program, run it in a profiler

Comment: I recommend `valgrind` as a profiler. You need the "callgrind" tool of valgrind. You can view the results nicely visualized with `kcachegrind`.

Comment: @n.m. `top` shows 1% CPU for my program and 94% CPU for XOrg. I will try with `valgrind`.

Comment: @n.m. `valgrind` can't run the program with: `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: rtld.c: 1284: dl_main: Assertion _rtld_local._dl_rtld_map.l_libname' failed!` Without valgrind the program runs slow, but properly.

Comment: Well it doesn't make much sense to run valgring on your program, since it's XOrg which hogs CPU. It's clearly an XOrg/driver problem. You may try to figure out which X11 API is to blame by disabling rendering calls one by one in your program and observing performance improvements. Maybe you can replace calls to slow APIs by something equivalent. You can also try running XOrg in valgrind, though for useful results you probably need its debug version. I have never seen this issue with valgrind, can you run a helloworld program in it? Could it be an architecture (x86/x86_64) mismatch somewhere?

Comment: @n.m. - valgrind works in general. My program is assembly written and does not contain any debug information. Also, some C/C++ conventions are possibly not observed. Anyway I have another ways to profile it. But how to blame XOrg, if everything else work like a charm?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39373/discussion-between-n-m-and-johnfound)

Comment: @n.m. - it is not a bad idea to post some answer in order to be able to accept the bounty. :)

Comment: Hm. I don't think there's a satisfactory solution. Other programs somehow manage decent text performance with the proprietary driver..

Comment: @n.m. Well, after this all long conversation, you are the only one that at least tried to help. There is still some little time and if someone suggest something really helpful he will get the bounty. If not, you should get it, but I will need an answer from you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although it can automaticly do (Apple designed Opencl for this purpose with their XQuartz API), X libraries aren't designed to use hardware acceleration. OpenGL and directX are well know to do it for 3D environments which you can typically find in games.

But you can also use it for 2D. Direct3D is designed to use polygons Direct2D is for plate graphics. In the beginning, OpenGl was designed to stay general purpose: So you have many functions you can use for hardware accelerated graphics.

Major X11 implementations includes GLX [DRI](https://dri.freedesktop.org/dri/) and Gallium.
I've never written something that use those API's, but I just know certain programs does accelerate theirs drawings by this way.

The performance benefit observed with the fallback VESA may have the following explanation:
The proprietary driver performs extra checks (eg. to see if it was asked to use hardware acceleration; then as it is regular Xlib it don't accel most of the time) whereas the fallback driver can't use hardware accelerations and go strait ahead to use CPU instead of GPU.